# A simple "javac" style command-line C/C++ compiler for Windows 7

Tags: c++, c, windows, compiler-construction, command-line

Over the last couple of months I practiced console programming with Java just with the help of JDK and a text editor of my choice (Notepad++). And I loved the simplicity as a program can be compiled from the command line plainly using `javac` and run using `java`.

Now, I'm looking for similar compiler for C/C++, such that I create a .c or .cpp file and compile it in the command prompt, and all it does is create a "native" executable that can be run directly from the command prompt. Thus, without any need of bloated IDE. The reason I'm looking for such simple compiler is because it is going to be used by high-school students so I'm advised to avoid any IDE as far as possible, so students can practice all the concepts of C/C++ languages without having to go for IDE. Which compiler can I use that does this job? also, I must work across all the versions Windows starting from Windows XP.

Comment: You can use `cl.exe` from the SDK. It is also shipped with all the versions of MSVS.

Comment: I'd _strongly_ disagree with the idea that a command line interface is somehow easier. Do you seriously expect them to write bug-free,  code on the first attempt, even typo-free?

Comment: @MSalters: I agree with you but I'm asked for a good suggestion for such requirement. so I am asking the same at best place. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) which is basically GCC for windows.

Then you can simply `gcc somefile.c` to create an executable.

Comment: I'm not sure whether its a Cygwin port or not as Cygwin, I guess, requires an additional flag which specifies the name of resultant executable and the syntax is something like `gcc -o somefile somefile.exe` and also one needs to run all these commands from Cygwin command prompt. So, does MinGW does the same job without its own command prompt?

Comment: MinGW itself is not cygwin and does not use/need cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

http://gcc.gnu.org/`gcc` is a multi platform c/c++ compiler

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio includes the ability to compile from the command line. Like others just said you can look at cygwin/MinGW. I would recommended using [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) or [Dev-C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/dev/devcpp.html). I know you stated you do not want an IDE, but I would highly suggest a minimalist IDE like the ones I just suggested, or at least [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to get some basic syntax highlighting with the ability to configure build tools if you want as well.

Comment: Ya I do have Notepad++ accompanied. But I avoid installing Visual Studio to avoid unnecessary bloat since whats the use to have it if students are not supposed to use any IDE.

Comment: If you really insist on using the command line then you can configure Notepad++ to use MinGW. I took APCS in high-school (C++) and then TAed for the class the following year (They just made the switch to java), I can understand not wanting to get students lost in an IDE. At the same time I think you may be going too far and students may get lost at the command line. If it were my class I would use Code::Blocks as you can just open a .cpp file, not have to worry about projects/workspaces, and then just click build or run. Also it is something students could easily setup at home.

Answer (score 2):

MinGW GCC is definitely the way go, but I would recomend the `nuwen.net` distro (http://nuwen.net/mingw.html). Haven't used it in a while (yay unix!), but if IIRC, it comes with everything ready to go after unpacking. The official distribution is ... very hard to get working.

Comment: What's the benefit of the Nuwen one? The MSI-distro of from MinGWs site worked fine for me. Still, if there is a better one I would love to try it out :)

Comment: I spot some nice things in there, like pre-packaged boost, libpng, libogg... The GCC I got is 4.5, it sports 4.6... okay, I'm convinced.

Comment: @Skurmedel, .msi is the windows installer files, right? I wasn't able to find anything like that; could you link to where you found it?

Comment: I don't blame you. The site is, hard to navigate. I can't find the page I used anymore. But it's "Automated MinGW Installer", pretty sure it's this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Automated%20MinGW%20Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20110316/

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution woul be [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), which provides an environment very similar to a UNIX shell. Then you can use the `make` utilities to compile your program.

Answer (score 1):

You should certainly consider using MinGW GCC, but not by download from the MiNGW web page, unless you are some kind of masochist. Get the one packaged by Twilight Dragon Media at http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net.

Answer (score 1):

I too use VisualStudio on Windows from the command prompt and use VS Make files as well.  That way, I can smb mount my source code from a different machine and perform compiles on several different platforms at once (e.g. Windows, Linux, Solarsi).